# How to reload list view after delete all item?

Tags: android, listview, reload

I have a delete all button and everytime it delete all item in a listview, the listview won't road but stay the same, they will reload only when I create a new item or restart this activity. I have print a log on my code and it seems that the list view reload before the delete method called. my code is this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);

    ArrayList<Inventory> listArray = new ArrayList<>();
    listArray.clear();
    listArray = db.read();
    if (listArray.size() == 0) {
        empty.setText("No Items");
    } else {
        empty.setText("");
    }
    ListViewAdapter customAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(listArray);
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    Button add_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addNewItem(view);
        }
    });

    Button button_deleteAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_deleteAll);
    button_deleteAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deteleAll();
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);

            final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);

            ArrayList<Inventory> listArray = new ArrayList<>();
            listArray.clear();
            listArray = db.read();
            Log.v("arraysize:", String.valueOf(listArray.size()));
            if (listArray.size() == 0) {
                empty.setText("No Items");
            } else {
                empty.setText("");
            }
            ListViewAdapter customAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(listArray);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
}
```

The method deleteAll() deletes all the data in SQLite.
I wish to know how to reload listview after this method called, rather than reload before this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the delete all method in your adapter. call the deleteAll method of your adapter whenever button was clicked. the deleteAll method would be like below:

```
public void setListArray(ArrayList arrayList)
{
//assuming your adapter list is named "listArray"
this.listArray = arrayList;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and in your button click simply write this code:

```
    button_deleteAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    //assuming your list of itames here is named "mListArray"
    mListArray.clear();
    adapter.setListArray(mListArray);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no need to initialize the customAdapter again in the button OnClick method. Also no need to setAdapter again.

Try to remove these lines in the onClick method.

Hope this fixes you issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `notifyDataSetChanged();` to your Adapter, inside a Listener. For example:

```
  myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view, int position, long id) {
           myArrayList.remove(position);
           myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```